# AudioTrack in streaming mode MODE_STREAMING

Tags: java, android, audio

I need to stream PCM data generated at runtime. So I have a thread with a loop

```
public void run() {
  while(...) {
    mAudioTrack.write(getPCM(), ...);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. It seems it doesn't depend on AudioTrack buffer size. I want it to be very small to simulate sort of low latency behaviour (150 ms) so the user can dinamically change the PCM picked by getPCM()

```
int bufferSize = 0.150 * sampleRate * channels * bitsPerSample / 8;
```

However, I tried to increase the buffer size up to 100k with no result

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is short example that works for me:

```
public class Internal extends Activity
{   
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);              
    }

    public void onPlayClicked(View v)
    {
        start();    
    }

    public void onStopClicked(View v)
    {
        stop();
    }

    boolean m_stop = false;
    AudioTrack m_audioTrack;
    Thread m_noiseThread;

    Runnable m_noiseGenerator = new Runnable()
    {       
        public void run()
        {
            Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);

            /* 8000 bytes per second, 1000 bytes = 125 ms */
            byte [] noiseData = new byte[1000];
            Random rnd = new Random();

            while(!m_stop)
            {           
                rnd.nextBytes(noiseData);   
                m_audioTrack.write(noiseData, 0, noiseData.length);                 
            }
        }
    };

    void start()
    {
        m_stop = false;

        /* 8000 bytes per second*/
        m_audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT, 8000 /* 1 second buffer */,
                                        AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);            

        m_audioTrack.play();        


        m_noiseThread = new Thread(m_noiseGenerator);
        m_noiseThread.start();
    }

    void stop()
    {
        m_stop = true;          
        m_audioTrack.stop();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Don't know what you mean. I cannot hear anything

Comment: This code works on two devices (both Samsung though). Check your LogCat logs, it should print all the details about `AudioTrack`.

Comment: Sure, I had to add a call to start() upon activity creation. Then it's a mistery it doesn't work with actual PCM data. Now I'm going to test with a machine-generated A 440hz sound

Comment: Sure, your code definetly solves the problem (in theory). Now I have to understand what's wrong with my code

Comment: @inazaruk How would you measure the average write delay? I modified your code a bit to play a fixed sound, and configured AudioTrack with a small buffer, so you can hear the underrunning. Here you are [the code](http://pastebin.com/5EWbPEKh) and [the eclipse proj](http://www.megaupload.com/?d=2LXPS1D0)

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question. What do you mean under write delay? How long it takes to play your buffer of X bytes?

Comment: Oh, I got it. You **do not** need to put `Thread.Sleep` in writer `AudioTrack` thread. The `AudioTracker.write` is blocking. It will only return, when there is free space in its buffer (size of which is specified in its constructor). So you shouldn't worry about buffer overflow and just remove `Sleep` method from writer thread.