# Generating a particular frequency tone and continue to play till stop button

Tags: android, audio, javasound

I am trying to build an app which can generate tones of arbitrary frequency..I got this
link: [Playing an arbitrary tone with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413426/playing-an-arbitrary-tone-with-android) which is really helpful..in that the tone is played for a particular duration which is set in code..I want to modify it such that the tone continues to play till the stop button is pressed..and not for a preset duration..I am unable to implement it..can someone please help with this?

Also I would like to know the reason for the click sound while starting and stopping a tone..and if there is any way to avoid this..I really need help with this..please help..

Answer (score 0):

An AudioTrack instance can operate under two modes: static or streaming.
So I think streaming mode may solve your problem.
In Streaming mode, the application writes a continuous stream of data to the AudioTrack, using one of the write() methods.

Please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179392/audiotrack-in-streaming-mode-mode-streaming). This may help you.

AudioTrack Class can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html).

Comment: already tried streaming mode..didnt work..the track I am generating lasts only for 3 seconds..and therefore stops at 3 seconds..will try out the suggestions..

Comment: I tried the posted link and it is generating sound continuously. It is not limited for 3 seconds.

Comment: which answer in that link did u try?..I tried the one with most votes..in that duration is specified and its 3 seconds..and mine stops playing after 3 seconds..

Comment: please try the answer from my shared [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179392/audiotrack-in-streaming-mode-mode-streaming)